# Eclipse [] is an unknown syslog facility error

Tags: java, eclipse, syslog

I'm trying to execute a program in eclipse and I when I click run I see this in the console output:

```
[] is an unknown syslog facility. Defaulting to [USER].
/
"Failed"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Code or it didnt happen.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that error is coming from [`org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/xref/org/apache/log4j/net/SyslogAppender.html), and that you've tried to set a bad facility name.  Go take a look at your appenders and how you are setting them up.

```
414   public
415   void setFacility(String facilityName) {
416     if(facilityName == null)
417       return;
418 
419     syslogFacility = getFacility(facilityName);
420     if (syslogFacility == -1) {
421       System.err.println("["+facilityName +
422                   "] is an unknown syslog facility. Defaulting to [USER].");
423       syslogFacility = LOG_USER;
424     }
425 
426     this.initSyslogFacilityStr();
427 
428     // If there is already a sqw, make it use the new facility.
429     if(sqw != null) {
430       sqw.setSyslogFacility(this.syslogFacility);
431     }
432   }
```

Comment: I commented the line in log4j.xml that was causing the syslog error but I still get / "Failed". When I open the Syslog.Appender.class eclipse says the log4j-1.2.12.jar can't be found. It's located at ~/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.12 and I've defined the M2_REPO variable.

Comment: The "Failed" isn't coming from the appender.  Look through your code and see what's printing it and why.